# 'No configuration file found and no entry configured via CLI option' in webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm writing my own webpack.config.js file for my personal project and I hit the error saying

`No configuration file found and no entry configured via CLI option.
When using the CLI you need to provide at least two arguments: entry and output.
A configuration file could be named 'webpack.config.js' in the current directory.
Use --help to display the CLI options.`

and my webpack file looks like

```
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
  template: __dirname + '/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
});

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  plugins: [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig],
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './'
  }

};
```

As you can see in my webpack.config.js, there are entry and output but webpack does not seem to recognize them for some reasons and I have not figured this out for a long time.

I'm running this webpack with `webpack-dev-server` via `"devBuild": "node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js"` in `package.json` file.

Has anyone had similar experience as mine and know how to make this work?

Thank you.

----------------------EDIT----------
Here is my project structure (sorry for not posting in the beginning)

```
root
|__client
|  |__React Folders
|  |__index.html
|  |__webpack.config.js
|
|__server
|  |__server.js
|
|__package.json
|__.babelrc
|__.gitignore
```

Let me know if you need something else.

Comment: Where in your project structure is your webpack config file?

Answer (score 0):

Move webpack.config.js in root directory

```
root
|__client
|  |__React Folders
|  |__index.html
|
|__server
|  |__server.js
|
|__package.json
|__.babelrc
|__.gitignore
|__webpack.config.js
```